# Accelerating a gas in a constant cross section tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Imagine a tube with a constant cross section with a body force on the fluid along the axis. Would it be possible for the gas to accelerate across the tube?

The volume element of an Ideal gas (no wander walls forces) that traversed a larger portion of the tube experiences a higher impulse and thus attains a higher velocity. However at low velocities, a gas can be approximated to be incompressible (constant density).

When a gas accelerates through a constant cross section, it's density should decrease as we move down the tube. So does this mean that an incompressible fluid does not accelerate but move with a constant velocity? And would this velocity be equal to the highest attainable velocity in the tube if the gas was Ideal with no wanderwalls forces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I could get out of your question, you essentially wish to understand the phenomenon of acceleration in a constant cross-section tube, in subsonic and supersonic regimes.

When a fluid is accelerated by a body force along a tube (of any cross-sectional area), it DOES GET ACCELERATED, meaning it's velocity increases. Now, the query arises in the following fact : If the mass is constant, which means rho*A*V is constant, then why doesn't the density decrease ? The explanation would be, in the subsonic regions, the velocity of the fluid doesn't and cannot increase so tremendously, so as to cause a change in density, owing to the presence of intermolecular van der Waals forces which act as a sort of internal damper in the fluid (you cannot accelerate the fluid beyond a certain range). Also, this phenomenon is extremely difficult to achieve using a constant cross-sectional area tube.

The phenomenon of Density change and subsequent increase in velocity can however be achieved by using a tube of varying cross-sectional area, essentially a Converging-Diverging Duct.

Comment: So, what you mean is that although the fluid gets accelerated through the fluid, the velocity does not rise enough to cause a change in density? But if there is difference of flow velocity at 2 cross sections of the tube, more gas should leave than enter. Wouldn't the only solution to this be a decrease in density? (Or constant velocity through the tube but increase in velocity when entering the tube for an incompressible flow)?